# Missing new line character at end of file

Tags: linux, opencv, intel-edison, opkg

I'm trying to install opencv on Intel Edison's linux os. I followed http://makezine.com/projects/make-43/photographic-memory/ in order to install it via opkg. However I get the following error, when run 
`opkg update`:

```
Collected errors:
 * parse_from_stream_nomalloc: Missing new line character at end of file!
 * parse_from_stream_nomalloc: Missing new line character at end of file!
 * parse_from_stream_nomalloc: Missing new line character at end of file!
 * parse_from_stream_nomalloc: Missing new line character at end of file!
```

Apparently due to this error, it cannot install any package. I looked thoroughly to find a solution but none of them worked. I appreciate your help.

Comment: im getting this as well, any update

Answer (score 2):

I found this sulution

cp /usr/lib/opkg/status /usr/lib/opkg/status.bak

rm /usr/lib/opkg/status

edit
nano /etc/config/fstab

and add "enabled_fsck" to force FS check at start-up

option 'enabled_fsck'   '1'

reboot;

and

Comment: 5 years later, and we're still left hanging for the next steps

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty easy error to fix, although I'm not sure why it is an error in the first place.

simply edit the offending file in `/var/lib/opkg`, go to the last line and add a newline

EX:

```
vi /var/lib/opkg/intel-iotdk
```

Comment: This is marvellous, but how to find which file is the offending one?

Comment: I can't remember. Just make sure they all have it? Are there a ton of files there? (don't forget to upvote if this helped you)

Comment: Tons of files indeed. Impossible without a script, and inefficient to write a script for this. The general line of thought is correct but unfortunately it did not help, ended up flushing.

Comment: From this: http://www.shr-project.org/trac/ticket/988 it appears the problem is with /var/opkg/status , due to a bug in opkg itself .... no workaround is suggested,